# Testing DOM in Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme

Let's say I have a tiny component like this:

**Button.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './Button.css';

export default class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <a href={ this.props.url } className={`button button-${ this.props.type }`}>
        { this.props.content }
      </a>
    );
  }
}
```

And there's some super basic styling like this:

**Button.css**

```
.button {
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button-primary {
  background-color: red;
}
.button-primary:hover {
  background-color: darkred
}

.button-secondary {
  background-color: aqua;
  color: black;
}
.button-secondary:hover {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  color: white;
}
```

And let's say I want to write some tests for this:

**Button.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

import Button from './Button';
import './Button.css';

// Render buttons
const primaryButton = mount(
  <Button 
    content="Primary button" 
    url="http://www.amazon.co.uk"
    type="primary"
  />
);
const secondaryButton = mount(
  <Button 
    content="Secondary button" 
    url="http://www.ebay.co.uk"
    type="secondary"
  />
);

it('should exist', () => {
  expect(primaryButton).toBeDefined();
  expect(secondaryButton).toBeDefined();
});

it('should display text in the button', () => {
  expect(primaryButton.text()).toEqual('Primary button');
});

it('should have the correct CSS classes', () => {
  expect(primaryButton.find('.button').hasClass('button-primary')).toEqual(true);
  expect(secondaryButton.find('.button').hasClass('button-secondary')).toEqual(true);
});
```

I've set this up using `react-create-app` and all the above works perfectly.

**My question is**: how do I test that what is getting rendered *looks* correct?  For example, in this case I would want to make sure that the buttons have the correct background colours defined in the CSS file and that they have the correct border radius.  This will prevent other developers accidentally overriding critical styling for example.

I was under the impression that Enzyme did this out of the box, but I cannot understand how to interrogate the virtual DOM which I assume is happening in the background? I thought that JSDOM was automatically running and I'm executing this from the CLI which is a Node environment.

I've tried this so far:

```
it('should have the correct background colours', () => {
  const domNode = primaryButton.find('.button').at(0).getDOMNode();
  const background = getComputedStyle(domNode).getPropertyValue('background');
  expect(background).toBe('red');
});
```

But `background` is returned blank, in fact if I do `console.log(getComputedStyle(domNode))` I get this returned which seems to be missing the styles:

```
  console.log src/modules/Button/Button.test.js:42
      CSSStyleDeclaration {
        _values: {},
        _importants: {},
        _length: 0,
        _onChange: [Function] }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to test computed property with external css sheet?

Answer (score 5):

The `getDOMNode` of an enzyme wrapper gets you the corresponding DOM node.

You can then use `getComputedStyle`  to get the style of that DOM:

```
const renderedComponent = mount(<MyComponent /);
const domNode = renderedComponent.find('div').at(0).getDOMNode();
const background = getComputedStyle(domNode).getPropertyValue('background');
expect(background).toBe('red');
```

Comment: `const domNode = primaryButton.find('div').at(0).getDOMNode();` - Throws: Method “getDOMNode” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.

Comment: It means you don't have any div. Did you try with `.button` instead of div ?

Comment: Ah, I see! Okay - yes, I have changed it to this: `const domNode = primaryButton.find('.button').at(0).getDOMNode();` which throws the error: ReferenceError: getComputedProperty is not defined.  Am I missing a library?

Comment: My bad, it is getComputedStyle, not getComputedProperty. Does it work with that change?

Comment: It very nearly does - this is the code I'm using: `const domNode = primaryButton.find('.button').at(0).getDOMNode();     const background = getComputedStyle(domNode).getPropertyValue('background');`  And if I  console.log(getComputedStyle(domNode)); then I get this: CSSStyleDeclaration {
        _values: {},
        _importants: {},
        _length: 0,
        _onChange: [Function] }  - it looks like that doesn't actually pull the styles in as I expected; the `background` property comes back empty.

Comment: Arf, it looks tricky. How is your css handled by jest? I think if you find a way to append your css file to the jsdom it might work but it looks more tricky than I thought

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if the CSS is loading in; I've just tried it with inline styles and the code you provided actually works so I'm guessing it's something to do with the external sheet...